# Cordova Push plugin Show Image in Status/Notification bar

Tags: cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working with a cordova app to send images as push notification. I am getting all payload data in cold start. How can I pass that data to notification bar? Notification bar only shows title and message. How can I pass other data?

Comment: What is your target platform?

Answer (score 0):

[PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) does not currently have this feature. To show an image in the notification bar, you will have to modify the plugin to create a notification with your image or any other data. It will depend on your target platform. For **Android**, I have submitted this pull request for [BigPictureStyle](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/498)